# IE11 probelm with array of objects (it works on Firefox and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm dynamically creating an array of objects like this:

```
let span = document.createElement('span')

span.classList.add('animated')
span.classList.add('char')

span.textContent = (char.match(/'|\.|\!|\?| |\,|\.|\;|\:|\./)) ? char  : '\ '

chars.push({
    char: char,
    span: span,
    solved: span.textContent === '\ ' ? false : true
 })
```

Later when I try to iterate through the array and accessing the element like this:

```
chars[i].span.classList.add('high-light')
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to get property 'span' of undefined or null reference

Why?

The full code is available here: https://github.com/sickdyd/secret-sentence

Comment: what you are getting in chars[i] ? is it undefined ?and what is char here ?

Comment: `char` in my assumption is not an array. Its a node list. NodeList has different definations for all browsers. You should take a look at it

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Show how you're setting `i`.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler (i.e. `Babel`) to convert es6 to es5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  // ...
  setTimeout(function() {
    chars[i].span.classList.add('high-light')
```

This is a **bug** in IE11. Variables declared with `let` syntax were officially introduced in ES2015, and IE11 was released in 2013 - although it does not throw a syntax error when encountering `let`, it does not conform to the specification. Specifically, variables declared with `let` in IE11 **do not** get block scoped - rather, they have function scope, just like `var`, so by the end of the loop, `i` is equal to `chars.length`, and `chars[chars.length]` is `undefined`, so trying to reference `chars[i].span` will throw an error.

I'd recommend avoiding `for` loops and using `forEach` instead, which will fix the problem and also let you avoid having to keep track of indicies:

```
chars.forEach(function(char) {
  // ...
  setTimeout(function() {
    char.span.classList.add('high-light')
    // ...
    // instead of referencing chars[i], reference char
```

You can also use the main [closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) example, though it's pretty ugly:

```
for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    // now, there will be a separate `i` argument for every iteration
    // ...
    setTimeout(function() {
      chars[i].span.classList.add('high-light')
      // ...
  })(i);
}
```

You can also consider automatically transpiling your code to be ES5 compatible with [Babel](https://babeljs.io).